# VGA Passtrough QEMU/KVM

Tags: virtualization

current i try to passtrough one of my GPU´s to a virtual machine (QEMU/KVM) via vfio-pci. My GPU´s are R9 290 and R9 390. I cant bind one of these cards to the PCI-Stub driver because both have the same Vendor and Device ID.

How it´s possible to passtrough one of these cards to a virtual machine?
Is it possible with XEN / pciback?